# How do I prove that $D_3\times \Bbb Z_2$ is not a cyclic group?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I have been told to 'show it's isomorphic to $D_{6}$, since we know $D_6$ is not cyclic'. I'm not sure how to do that, or how can I prove it using a different approach.

Comment: You can use the definition of a cyclic group, and show that no element generates the entire group.

Comment: Provide an isomorphism with $D_6$. (Which elements are reflections? Which are rotations?)

Comment: Are cyclic groups abelian?

Comment: So is it enough to say that $D_3 \times \mathbb{Z_2}$ is not abelian (since $D_3$ is not). And since cyclic groups are abelian, our group is not cyclic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic groups. However, $D_3=S_3$ is a group which is not cyclic, because it is not even abelian. Hence $D_3\times C_2$ is not cyclic.

Comment: Does that imply that the converse of your statement is true? 
Namely, If a group has a non-cyclic subgroup, then the group is non-cyclic?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $(\rho,\bar{0})\cdot(\sigma,\bar{0})=(\rho\circ\sigma,\bar{0})\neq(\rho^{-1}\circ\sigma,\bar{0})=(\sigma\circ\rho,\bar{0})=(\sigma,\bar{0})\cdot(\rho,\bar{0})$, thus $D_3\times C_2$ is not commutative and thus not cyclic.